# Oracle client tools 11g for mac, imp command

Tags: macos, oracle

Do you happen to now if **imp** oracle command is included in the oracle client tools 11g for MAC OS?

Actually I have download the packages but I can't seem to find it and I am wondering if there is a trick for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have downloaded is the 'Instant Client'.  This is basically a sub-set of the Oracle client, just for connecting to the database.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html).

The Instant Client does not include admin utilities such as IMP.  For that you need the standard client, which is basically the full database software.  However, 10g was the only version ever available for MAC OS.  I guess the demand wasn't there.  How many MAC OS servers are there?

Comment: Hi APC thank you for the information. Actually no servers. It is for my macbook machine which I use for development. I know I can do import remotely - and I use it of course -  but the thing is, is that the app is in such way that it has many test scenarios that use direct imports so I need it locally.

Comment: I know you're not intending to use your Mac Book as a server; I was just explaining why Oracle abandoned doing Oracle database for the Mac, and hence why you won't be able to get IMP.